# Filter by tags in big-commerce blog

Tags: blogs, bigcommerce

I am using Built in Blog in Big-commerce ,But i am facing some problem that their is not filter for blogs posts.

i want to fetch some specified blogs posts based on tags.

example :

TAG1(BL) [image: TAG1 exmaple]

TAG2(BG) : [image: TAG2 Example]

Here is blog page code:

```
                <div class="Content" id="LayoutColumn2">
                    <div class="BlockContent PageContent">
                        <h1>%%GLOBAL_BlogTitle%%</h1>
                         %%SNIPPET_RecentPostsContent%%
                    </div>
                    </div>
```

AND using this code i can get tags

```
                    %%GLOBAL_BlogTags%%
```

Now i want to filter all the blog posts which  is having blog tags "BG".

how can i filter ? i was searching for so many online source nothing was helps me much

Useful helps will much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a built-in feature that supports filtering by Blog Tag. Neither the templating offers this nor is there a workaround through the API. The Blog Tags resource in the API only offers the ability to list tags and the Blog Post object doesn't expose the blog tags field.

At best, you might be able to parse the posts on the blog home/its pages to offer the filtering, but it may be slow depending on how many pages worth of entries and how many users are attempting to do so.

Comment: parsing will be based on what ?